# Can't delete file in a USB Key

Tags: mac, usb, disk-format, fat32

Deleting file on a usb key has become impossible since I try to export photo from an Iphone to an external USB key with the application "photos".

The Usb key continue to work properly when reading it. (We can still open anything on the key).
But add file, rename file or deleting file is impossible.

I try all what google have to purpose :

- Right click on read information. As you can see "*partage et permissions*"("*sharing and permissions*") can not be modify. "*Lecture seulement*" means "*read only*".

[image]

- I try to use disk utility to try running S.O.S, also to try reformating disk.
  Here is the error I get :

```
Running S.O.S. on "NO NAME" (disk2s1)

Repairing file system.
The volume is already unmounted.
Running fsck_msdos -y /dev/rdisk2s1
** /dev/rdisk2s1 (NO WRITE)

** Phase 1 - Preparing FAT

** Phase 2 - Checking Directories

** Phase 3 - Checking for Orphan Clusters

Found orphan cluster(s)

Fix? no

Found 43 orphaned clusters

Free space in FSInfo block (1065976) not correct (1065974)

Fix? no

892 files, 34111168 KiB free (1065974 clusters)

File system check exit code is 8.
Reverting to original state: unmounted.
File system check or repair failed: (-69845)

The operation has failed...
```

- trying to use command line to change right

```
~ ls -la /Volumes/NO\ NAME/* 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 boris  staff   2283166 14 avr 20:36 IMG_0417.jpeg
...
~ sudo chmod -v u+rw  /Volumes/NO\ NAME/*
~ ls -la /Volumes/NO\ NAME/* 
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 boris  staff   2283166 14 avr 20:36 IMG_0417.jpeg
...
~ sudo rm -rf /Volumes/NO\ NAME/* 
rm: /Volumes/NO NAME/IMG_0200.jpeg: Read-only file system
...
```

Notice that is strange because I can't rename **IMG_0200.jpeg** even if there are `-rwxrwxrwx@`

- Here is what saying testdisk :

[image]

- I also try on windows to use diskpart to reformat. The problem was the same than testdisk
- Obviously propiety file didn't work too.

Hope someone can help me, and don't use photos application to export yours images...

Comment: Try a different USB flash to see if you can perform the same actions.  Your USB might be dying

Comment: My first suggestion is to copy all the files you can off the USB key thumb drive to another drive ASAP. The 'orphan cluster' and 'Free space' errors are significant enough that macOS has marked the drive's file system as being read-only, in an attempt to not further lose data by overwriting crucial areas of the drive. This is the reason you are not able to delete files. Secondly, if you use USB keys only on a Mac, not Windows, etc, reformat _a new drive_ to HFS+ or APFS.

Comment: If a USB stick/SD card has a write error, the firmware protection will kick in & lock the device to read-only. The upshot of this is you can [may be] able to retrieve data from it, but it will no longer write or format. This is, to all intents & purposes, irreversible. See https://superuser.com/questions/1125282/what-can-i-do-if-my-usb-flash-drive-is-write-protected-or-read-only for fuller details.

Comment: @Allan, Other Usb work fine.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I just tried to flash the USB to reset the firmware but I couldn't. I will ask to a shop reparator monday what is the problem. Do you think this question is not appropriate to apple.stackexchange and should be on superuser ?

Comment: It gets asked everywhere, a lot. Superuser just already has several comprehensive QA on it. Basically, the fix is "throw it away & get a new one". It's not worth the effort or expense to fix & will likely fail again even if you did. They're very fragile. Consider them disposable & never to be trusted.

Comment: What @Tetsujin said.  Your USB is dying. Recover what you can then toss it in the bin.